# The influence of a potentiometer on photo-diode bias

Tags: arduino, sensor, potentiometer

I have a sensor which I have connected to an Arduino via SerialPort to get data readings.

There is a "screw potentiometer" (It's a screw that changes resistance which affects the output voltage).

If I decrease the resistance, my AnalogOutput of my Arduino gives me greater voltage units when my sensor is not exposed to what it is supposed to sense.
However, the maximum value is the same as before.

Have I decreased my sensitivity or increased it?

I have definitely narrowed my range of output values.

[Here](http://sharp-world.com/products/device/lineup/data/pdf/datasheet/gp2y1010au_e.pdf) is a link to the sensor DataSheet

[image]

Comment: It isn't clear what you are describing. If you provide a schematic (even a simplified one), we will be able to assist you much more accurately. Cheers and welcome!

Comment: At first it sounded like you are just adjusting the offset voltage of the sensor and I would expect the peak signal value, minus the offset value would be the same. Assuming you are not hitting the end-stops on the ADC input, the information confuses me so I'd definitely post a circuit

Comment: In case you do not have sufficient reputation on this site to add a schematic, please make one, or even sketch one on paper and take a picture, and upload it to any public image sharing site. Share that link here in a comment, and someone with edit privileges will incorporate it into your question.

Comment: those screw potentiometers are called "trim pots" by those who pretend they know what they're talking about (me too!)

Comment: We need to see inside the "Amplifier Circuit," or else we're just guessing (although it's mostly likely just a single op-amp inverting configuration). Is this figure from a datasheet? Please link.

Comment: Where are you connecting your potentiometer? Between what and what?

Answer (score 1):

You probably just have your variable resistance (potentiometer) installed in the upper portion of your voltage divider. You can play with a [virtual one](http://www.flashscience.com/electricity/voltage_divider.htm) here and see the effect.

UPDATE (after schematic with photodiode was added):

It's impossible to say what's going on exactly because the "Amplifier Circuit" is drawn as a box, but in general...

when you decrease the bias resistance of the photodiode you are increasing the ratio of dark current to signal current which reduces the sensitivity and increases the offset (results in the behavior you describe with a higher voltage in zero light).

Sensitivity is the ratio:

$$\frac{\mbox{change out}}{\mbox{change in}}$$

Getting less voltage difference out, for the same light difference in is a decrease in sensitivity.

UPDATE2:

According to the datasheets [here](https://circuithub.com/parts/SHARP/GP2Y1010AU0F) (click documents), Rs *isn't accessible*! Where are you connecting your potentiometer?

Comment: Noted. I will get a schematic in a bit

Comment: Schematic added. I change Rs as I rotate the screw.

Comment: Oh!!! Your question has nothing to do with the potentiometer and everything to do with the photo-diode.

Comment: I added a link to the Sensor DataSheet

Comment: That datasheet shows that Rs isn't externally accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet says almost nothing other than "don't change the resistor or the calibration is gone"  and they don't tell you what the internal circuitry is.  Not that there is anything wrong wit that.  Breaking things is always good, lots of learning to be had.

What the issue is, is that you can't be certain, you could have decreased the sensitivity or you could have increased the sensitivity but now it is clipping at a lower level so only appears to be putting out the same level at maximum.

The sensitivity you care to measure is the actually the slope of the the curve of figure #3.

Since you've messed with it and you don't know what is inside the only way to answer the question is to reconstruct a family of curves for varying levels of the \$R_s\$.  You should end up with a curve similar to figure #3 for each of the \$R_s\$ values.  Once you have that then you'll know.

Unless someone here has done exactly what you have done and done the experiment, or if you find the internal schematic or if you take it apart and reverse engineer the schematic this is probably your only option.